# Kubuntu - Dolphin panel - hide "Recently Saved" and "Search For"

Tags: kubuntu, dolphin

In the Dolphin file manager, is there any way to hide *"Recently Saved"* and *"Search For"* in the side panel on the left-hand side? I never use either of these, and they get in my way because I have to scroll down to get to *"Devices"* if my Dolphin window isn't large enough.

[image: DolphinBrowser]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Places**

Dolphin handbook

Dolphin > Help > Dolphin Handbook (F1)

or

online: https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/dolphin/index.html

> Places
>
> A right mouse button click opens the context menu to
>   edit, add, hide or remove entries and change the icon size to one of
>   the predefined values or lock/unlock the panels.

Right clicking - hiding and unhiding:

[image]

**Future ?**

Bug 300247 - Allow hiding individual groups in new Places Panel: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=300247

Under review - Hidding Group from KFilePlacesModel: https://phabricator.kde.org/D8367

Comment: Thanks for that! I should have RTFM'ed. I knew you could "hide" entries, I just didn't realize that if you hide all the entries under a particular section, then the section header disappears (this wasn't very clear, and it's not very intuitive - I was expecting to be able to right-click on the section heading itself to hide the section).

Comment: Maybe in the future: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=300247 , https://phabricator.kde.org/D8367